# locate psycopg2 cursor in module

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, psycopg2, cx-oracle

I have different applications sharing same databases. For simplification purpose I want to concentrate all database connectivity stuff in one module, named mylib/init_pg.py

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
pg_cnx = psycopg2.connect(dbname='db', host='x.x.x.x', user='u', password='xxx')
pg_cnx.autocommit = True
pg = pg_cnx.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
```

then from my different applications I just have to

```
from mylib.init_pg import *
pg.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable;")
...
pg.close()
pg_cnx.close()
```

problem is : once it has run once, cursor and connection are closed.
and another run doesn't refresh it, it stays closed.

one solution would be to `importlib.reload(mylib.init_pg)`. Importlib doc states

> If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the from statement, another is to use import and qualified names (module.name) instead.

so according doc, `from mylib.init_pg import *` should be enough, no ? but in fact it doesn't refresh and I have an Exception "cursor is closed" when pg.execute(). How to solve this kind of issue ? Same issue with cx_Oracle connection/cursors.